# How can I set up multiple network adapters with same settings?

Tags: networking, network-adapter, gigabit-ethernet

I have a computer that's going to have 5 NICs with 4 ports each. I need to configure each adapter to use specialized settings such as Jumbo Frames, receive buffers of 2048, etc.

Is it possible to configure one adapter, export the settings, then import those settings into the other adapters?

This will use a Windows OS. Either 7, 8 or 10.

**Results of using netsh to set JumboFrames on Win10 adapter named "Ethernet 6":**
The adapter properties window was opened after the command line arguments were completed. Available options in the dropdown are Disabled/4088/9014.

[image]

Comment: First, you should tell us what operating system are you using on this machine.

Comment: @pbies This is currently in planning stages, so the OS is undecided. It will either be Windows 7, 8 or 10.  It will be installed in a manufacturing plant.

Comment: For such interfaces you should use Linux/Unix. If this would be rather Windows, you should use Server for optimal performance.

Comment: @pbies In this situation Windows is an absolute requirement. Thus far we haven't had a need to run on Windows Server.  If it impacts the answer to my question I'd consider switching.

Comment: You could use the `netsh` command. See [Technet - Using netsh](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490939.aspx) and a Dell KB [Windows Server: How to Configure Jumbo Frames in a Server Core Installation of Windows Server 2008](http://www.dell.com/support/article/ie/en/iebsdt1/SLN289670).

Comment: @Zina I started with netsh. Although netsh shows success when setting jumboframes, when viewing the adapter's advanced properties, jumboframes is still marked as disabled.

Comment: You did it from an elevated prompt? Can you enable them in properties and see if you can read the setting. Can you post your output? Have you changed the name to be correct?